# Java - Multiple constructors using same data type

Tags: java

How can we create constructor, to set different values that are from same data type?

Its impossible two create two identical constructors:

```
public User(int age, String name){
}  
public User(int age, String surname){
}
```

User user1 = new User(33, **Jack**);
User user2 = new User(33, **Sparrow**);

Since both name and surname are from same data type, its impossible to know which value the user has meant to set.

---

We can create a constructor that has all the properties and then pass null for unset arguments.

```
public User(int age, String name, String surname){
}
```

User user1 = new User(33, **Jack**);
User user2 = new User(33, null, **Sparrow**);

---

There is a way to make it, using HashMap imitating the javascript object literal.

```
package javaapplication;

import java.awt.Color; 
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JavaApplication {

    public static class User {

        public int age;
        public String name;
        public String surname;
        public Color hairColor;

        public User(HashMap<String, Object> arguments) {

            if (arguments.containsKey("hairColor")) {
                this.hairColor = (Color) arguments.get("hairColor");
            }

            if (arguments.containsKey("name")) {
                this.name = (String) arguments.get("name");
            }

            if (arguments.containsKey("surname")) {
                this.surname = (String) arguments.get("surname");
            }

            if (arguments.containsKey("age")) {
                this.age = (int) arguments.get("age");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        User jack1 = new User(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("hairColor", Color.RED);
                put("name", "Jack");
                put("age", 33);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(jack1.hairColor);  // java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
        System.out.println(jack1.surname);    // null
        System.out.println(jack1.name);       // Jack
        System.out.println(jack1.age);        // 33

        User jack2 = new User(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("hairColor", Color.RED);
                put("surname", "Sparrow");
                put("age", 33);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(jack2.hairColor);    // java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
        System.out.println(jack2.surname);      // Sparrow
        System.out.println(jack2.name);         // null
        System.out.println(jack2.age);          // 33

    }

}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: new User().setName(name).setSurname(surname).setAge(age). Or 'static User createUsingSurname(..., surname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical ways of doing this are with static creation methods or a builder object.

Static creation methods are the way to go if there are distinctive patterns of usage. For your example (where this perhaps isn't the case).

```
public static User ageName(int age, String name) {
    ...
}  
public static User ageSurname(int age, String surname) {
    ...
}
...
```

In general it's a good idea to avoid any overloading. With constructors Java rather forces you into it, but sometimes you have to break free.

Builder may go something like:

```
public class UserBuilder { // This could be made a nested class of User
    private int age = -1;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Color hairColor;

    public UserBuilder age(int age) {
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }
    // ... other properties ...
    public User build() {
        // Or return new User(this)
        return new User(age, name, surname, hairColor);
    }
}
```

This uses the typical Java dirty hack of returning `this` in a builder so you can build a train wreck.

```
User user1 = new UserBuilder().age(33).name("Jack").build();
```

**You really need real examples of usage to see how it should fit in.**

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating things by using a HashMap here. Instead you could make use of the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for the same.

```
class User {
    // required parameters
    private int age;

    // optional parameters
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    private User(UserBuilder userBuilder) {
        this.age = userBuilder.age;
        this.name = userBuilder.name;
        this.surname = userBuilder.surname;
    }

    public static class UserBuilder {
        // required parameters
        private int age;

        // optional parameters
        private String name;
        private String surname;

        public UserBuilder setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(this);
        }

    }
}
```

Now you can use it :

```
User user1 = new User.UserBuilder(12).setName("Jack").build();
User user2 = new User.UserBuilder(12).setSurname("Sparrow").build();
```

This assumes that `age` is a *mandatory* field, `name` and `surname` are *optional* fields for creating an object of `User`. You can tweak it as per your requirement accordingly.